# Materialized view refresh on selected data - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a Mview which needs to be refreshed on different timezones based on the countries. Multiple country details will be present in the table.

```
  Sample Table:

        Country Country_Name Data1 Data2
        1       India          x     y
        2       USA            z     w
        3       Brazil         r     t
        .       ...            .     .
```

I want India data to be refreshed at 3:00 PM IST and USA data at 5:00PM IST.

Is it possible to do like that? I understand we can create multiple mviews based on country and refresh but just want to know whether there is any other option.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You'll probably need to refresh the whole MV every hour.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to restrict a `refresh on demand` to a part (subset of rows) of a given materialized view: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_MVIEW.html#GUID-DD332F65-A5BC-4DE6-814E-EAE2E0275F3D. A `refresh on demand` always targets the whole mview: so I think the answer to your question is: no.